# Why is this archive failing to create symlinks?

Tags: debian, symbolic-link, tar

When I extract the archive [Symfony_Standard_2.2.1.tgz](http://symfony.com/download?v=Symfony_Standard_2.2.1.tgz) using this command:

```
$ tar xzf /home/tomas/downloads/Symfony_Standard_2.2.1.tgz
```

I always get the errors:

```
tar: doctrine.php: Cannot create symlink to `../vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine.php': Operation not supported
tar: doctrine: Cannot create symlink to `../vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine': Operation not supported
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

### Why is it failing to create the symlinks?

---

```
$ tar --version
tar (GNU tar) 1.23
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later .
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by John Gilmore and Jay Fenlason.
```

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.7 (squeeze)
Release:        6.0.7
Codename:       squeeze
```

Comment: To which filesystem are you extracting? I'm guessing it's one that doesn't support symlinks? Like FAT

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Pylsa](https://superuser.com/users/34844/pylsa)'s comment said it all. I didn't consider the fact that I'm working on a VMware shared folder from a Windows machine with NTFS partitions. Extracting the archive anywhere on the virtual machine works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I'm coming a bit late to this party, but had the same problem yesterday. If the filesystem does not support symlinks and you despite want all the contents from the archive to be accessible, it might be a workaround to copy those files (which should be symlinked).

The archive I wanted to extract had 20+ symlinks, so I decided to generate the `cp`commands by a script. I just need to provide the `stderr` output of `tar` (via a file by `tar ... 2> /tmp/tar-stderr.txt`) and the target folder. I decided to not yet execute the `cp` commands, but pipe them to a file which I can check before I `chmod +x` and execute it. Feel free to improve the script, pipe tar directly to it (e.g. by [exchanging `stdout`/`stderr`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2381643)), use somehow `tee` to provide the ignored messages of `tar`...

```
#!/bin/sh
(export DIR=/your/extraction/target/directory; echo \#\!/bin/sh -e; cat /tmp/tar-stderr.txt | grep 'Cannot create symlink to' | sed -e 's7^tar: \.\([^:]\+\): Cannot create symlink to .\([^:]\+\).*$7\1:\27' -e "s7^\(.\+\)/\([^:]\+\):\(.\+\).\$7cd $DIR\1 \&\& cp \3 \2;7")
```

EDIT: Explanation of script added:

The `grep` filters the lines of interest.
My `sed` commands are simple, but use `7` as field delimiter instead of the common `/`. With this I can search for and/or write `/`.

The first `sed` expression filters the relevant information (relative path and the 2 filenames) and puts a `:` as delimiter. The second distinguishes filename from path and throws away the `'` at the very end; the final output then is a `cp` command.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem that I wanted to copy a large folder from one hard drive to a new one but took a while for me to consider the different partition formats.

The original was on an `ext4` formatted partition on the extraction location was an external drive formatted as `exFat`. Once I realized this I formatted the external hard drive to ext4 and it worked, but I also used the `-h` flag for de-refenrencing symlinks.

```
tar -xhf myfolder.tar
```

I was using Ubuntu 22.04, for additional details.

Wanted to share this experience in case someone else finds it helpful.